# Autocomplete component - adding range selection between 2 items using shift key - react js

Tags: reactjs, node.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axiosAuth from "../../axiosAuth";
import { Autocomplete } from "@mui/lab";
import { TextField } from "@mui/material";

const NaceKods = ({ selectChange, init }) => {
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (init) {
      setSelectedValues(init ? JSON.parse(init) : []);
    }
  }, [init]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const v = JSON.stringify(selectedValues);
    selectChange("Nacekods", v);
  }, [selectedValues]);
  
  const handleChange = (_, newInputValue) => {
    setInputValue(newInputValue);
  };

  const handleSelect = (_, newValue) => {
    setSelectedValues(newValue);
  };

  const getNaceKod = () => {
    axiosAuth.get("/NaceKods").then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getNaceKod();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        options={data.map((val) => val.naceKodu)}
        value={selectedValues}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={handleChange}
        onChange={handleSelect}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option === value}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Arama - NaceKods" />
        )}
        disableCloseOnSelect={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default NaceKods;
```

I've attempted various solutions, but none have worked for me. I'm looking to add functionality that allows the selection of a wide range between two items, such as selecting options 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7 when pressing SHIFT + 2, and SHIFT + 6, resulting in the selection of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.